# getting data with sequelize and express.js into ionic

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework, sequelize.js

I have been struggling with this for a while now and can't find anything on the Internet about it, so I was wondering if somebody has any experience getting data in Ionic with [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) and the routing with [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

This is wat I got:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var cars = require('./routes/cars') (app);

app.use('/cars', cars);
```

**routes/cars.js**

```
var models  = require('../models');
var express = require('express');
var router    = express.Router();

router.get('/cars', function(req, res) {
  models.Car.findAll()
  .then(function(data){
      res.json(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
      console.log("ops: " + error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'error' });
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**models/cars.js**

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Car = sequelize.define("Car", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        favorite:  DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'car'
    });
    return Car;
};
```

I have tried multiple ways to get this to work, but when I go to http://localhost:8100/cars the browser outputs:

```
Cannot GET /cars
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `express.Router()`, you need to tell the app to use your router:
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router

```
router = require('./routes/cars')
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have added this also, but still get the same error. I have updated it in my question.

Comment: You are exposing the route on `/cars/cars` - `app.use` will expose the router your pass as sub-routes on the route. Look at the example on http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router

Comment: in the `app.use()` i'm referring to the `route/cars.js`. There is where I use the router.Express. So it is included

Comment: Yes - it is included twice :). In `routes/car.js` you are creating a sub-router and telling it to listen to `/cars`. In `app.js` you are importing this sub-router and telling your main router to attach this sub-router on `/cars` which means your router will listen on `/cars/cars`

Answer (score 0):

You exposed the route '/cars' in app.js, and '/cars' as a subroute in cars.js resulting in '/cars/cars'